# Login to SugarCRM by setting access tokens to local storage

Tags: authentication, access-token, sugarcrm

Is it possible and save to log in to Sugar stright after geting tokens from

```
POST /rest/v10//oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: site.cz
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache

{
"grant_type":"password",
"client_id":"sugar",
"client_secret":"",
"username":"karel",
"password":"pass",
"platform":"base"
}
```

like:

```
window.localStorage.setItem(‘prod\:SugarCRM:AuthAccessToken', '\'8ce80b69-ba6b-7421-eef1-57b5b6768d07\'');
window.localStorage.setItem(‘prod\:SugarCRM:AuthRefreshToken', '\'2ce80b69-ba6b-7421-eef1-57b5b6as8d07\'');
window.localStorage.setItem(‘prod\:SugarCRM:AuthDownloadToken', '\'a0980b69-ba6b-7421-eef1-57b5b6as8d07\'');
```

I tried this and it looks like everything is just fine, but my colleague is concerned, that by doing this, we have bypassed some login steps and some services might not work.

Is he right or will everything work correctly?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with that.  The login token will work for a period of time over multiple calls so saving it only makes sense.

Comment: what about bwc, entryPoints, soap... will this work?